# objective-c metadataOutputRectOfInterestForRect return {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

Updated!!!

I'm using `metadataOutputRectOfInterestForRect` to convert rectangle in order to use `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` rectOfInterest. But when translate to `CGRect`, it always return 0.

**Here is my code:**

```
NSError *error;

AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:captureDevice error:&error];

if (!input) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    return NO;
}

_captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
[_captureSession addInput:input];

_videoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:_captureSession];
[_videoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
[_videoPreviewLayer setFrame:_viewPreview.bounds];
[_viewPreview.layer addSublayer:_videoPreviewLayer];
[_viewPreview bringSubviewToFront:_lblGuide];
[_viewPreview bringSubviewToFront:_vFocus];

CGRect visibleMetadataOutputRect = [_videoPreviewLayer metadataOutputRectOfInterestForRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
NSLog(@"--- log convert: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(visibleMetadataOutputRect));
NSLog(@"--- log _videoPreviewLayer: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(_videoPreviewLayer.bounds));
NSLog(@"--- log _viewPreview: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(_viewPreview.bounds));

_captureMetadataOutput = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
[_captureSession addOutput:_captureMetadataOutput];

_dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
[_captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:_dispatchQueue];
[_captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]];
[_captureMetadataOutput setRectOfInterest:visibleMetadataOutputRect];

[_captureSession startRunning];

return YES;
```

And the NSlog resut:

```
[5082:1768978] --- log convert: {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
[5082:1768978] --- log _videoPreviewLayer: {{0, 0}, {320, 468}}
[5082:1768978] --- log _viewPreview: {{0, 0}, {320, 468}}
```

Please help me to resolve it.

Comment: can you give us the log of ```_viewPreview.bounds``` and ```_videoPreviewLayer.bounds```. Might need to set the visible bounds after you have set up those views.

Comment: @BenAvery I has updated more log. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I found a simple solution and it worked for me.

Just move 2 line of code right after `[_captureSession startRunning]`

```
CGRect visibleMetadataOutputRect = [_videoPreviewLayer metadataOutputRectOfInterestForRect:self.vFocus.frame];
    [_captureMetadataOutput setRectOfInterest:visibleMetadataOutputRect];
```

It work well!